# Why doesn't _tokenApprovals get reset after calling transferFrom in OpenZeppelin's implementation of ERC721?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin

Imagine A gives permission to B to transfer tokenId==111. That is, _tokenApprovals[111]=B.
B executes transferFrom and sends the token to himself.
Later, through some exchange for example, B sells the token 111 to another person, without having modified _tokenApprovals[111]. Couldn't he send the token to himself again, because _tokenApprovals[111] is still equal to B?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly why in the transfer() method they clear approvals. Which does reset _tokenApprovals.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L341

```
  // Clear approvals from the previous owner
  _approve(address(0), tokenId);
```

Comment: thanks man! somehow I missed that part of the code